# resposta com array vazio mongodb + vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mongodb, axios

estou fazendo o front de uma aplicação bem boba apenas pra treinar,o backend ja esta todo feito e rodando certinho testei varias vezes com insominia,so que agora no front nao consigo pegar os dados no banco (MongoDB) sempre me retorna um array vazio na resposta.

```
Aqui vai o script vue

import Maquinas from '../services/maquinas'

export default {
    name: "home",
    data(){
        return {
        maquinas:[]   
        }
    }
,
   mounted(){
     Maquinas.listar().then(resposta => {
       console.log(resposta)})
    }
}
```

Aqui vai o meu servico que esta fazendo a chamada ao banco ja com a BaseURL configurada

```
import {http} from './config'

export default{

    async listar( ){
        const user_id = localStorage.getItem('user')
        const resposta = await http.get('/maquinas',
        {headers : {user_id}})
        console.log(resposta)
}
```

ja tentei muita coisa mais sempre retorna o data vazio

Comment: Consegues abrir diretamente no browser a página `/maquinas` e ver os dados?

Comment: nao,la tambem retorna um array vazio :(  pior que e so o data que retorna vazio o resto vem tudo ok

Comment: _"so o data que retorna vazio o resto vem tudo ok!_? podes explicar melhor? De qq maneira se abrindo a página no browser não mostra nada o problema é no servidor. Coloca esse código...

Comment: vou pegar aqui,mais o engracado e que no insominia vem tudo ok

Comment: aqui esta o repositorio no github :  https://github.com/JaimeAcacio/Maquinas/tree/master/src